# Grails JMS Plugin - Unable to resolve classes

Tags: grails, jms

I'm pretty new to grails so it's possible that i've missed something obvious, but I am trying to utilise the [JMS plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/jms). I've included the following within the plugins section of my BuildConfig.groovy

```
compile ":jms:1.2"
```

However when I compile the app I get lots of "unable to resolve class" exceptions for imports within the jms plugin (40 in total, javax.jms.* and org.springframework.jms.* mostly).

e.g.

```
| Error Compilation error: startup failed:
C:\dev\prj\grails\tApp\target\work\plugins\jms-1.2\grails-app\utils\DefaultJmsBe
ans.groovy: 16: unable to resolve class org.springframework.jms.listener.Default
MessageListenerContainer
@ line 16, column 1.
import org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer
^

C:\dev\prj\grails\tApp\target\work\plugins\jms-1.2\grails-app\services\grails\pl
ugin\jms\JmsService.groovy: 22: unable to resolve class javax.jms.Message
@ line 22, column 1.
import javax.jms.Message
```

Is anyone able to point me in the right direction? The issue can be reproduced just by adding the plugin to the BuildConfig.groovy as mentioned above to a new grails project .

Grails version 2.3.3

Many thanks

Tom

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried executing the command `grails refresh-dependencies` before running `grails run-app`?

I wrote a blog post on [installing a Grails plugin](http://www.inoneo.com/en/blog/2/grails/installing-a-grails-plugin) if you need more details.

Answer (score 0):

While doing a Grails 2.2 -> 2.3.4 upgrade I ran into a similar issue and was able to get things working by manually adding spring-jms to my dependencies in BuildConfig.groovy:

```
compile 'org.springframework:spring-jms:3.2.5.RELEASE'
```

It's odd that this would stop working now of course, since the jms plugin hasn't changed in a very long time.  My guess is that it depends on the spring-jms lib, but didn't have it listed as a dependency, instead relying on grails to bring it in.  According to the [2.3.x upgrade guide](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/guide/upgradingFromPreviousVersionsOfGrails.html), there have been changes to what grails brings in now, so perhaps spring-jms stopped getting a free ride.

Comment: Hey thanks for the tip,  will give that a try when I'm back at work :-)

Answer (score 0):

The Grails MX website has a write-up that might help; it's built using 2.3.4:

http://grails.org.mx/2013/12/20/quickstart-jms-en-grails/

It was pretty helpful to me in getting a sample application up and running.  It's in Spanish though, so may need to have Google translate it for you...